# yhmath's incompatible length of | and others ( () and [] and {} and \/ and ...)

Tags: delimiters, yhmath

The following code

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{yhmath}
\begin{document}
    \[
        \left(
            \rule{10pt}{10pt}
        \middle|
            \rule[-5pt]{10pt}{5pt}
        \right]
    \]
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: left parenthesis vs vertical bar vs right bracket]

It appears that the bar is (significantly) longer than `(` and `]`.
Why does this happen?
And is it possible to make every delimiter the same height
(other than not using yhmath)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're out of luck, with just `yhmath`, sorry.

Probably in order to save slots for further symbols, the font designer chose to define the metric for the extensible vertical bar as

```
(CHARACTER O 14
   (CHARWD R 0.333334)
   (CHARDP R 0.580007)
   (VARCHAR
      (REP O 14)
      )
   )
```

This means that the base character (from the symbol font) will never satisfy the constraints for a delimiter, because it has height zero, so it will replicate itself and you get an oversized one.

Is all lost? No. You still have the standard `largesymbols` font available. So you can reset the vertical bar to the standard.

#### Only `yhmath`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{yhmath}

\newcommand{\test}[1]{%
  \left(
    \vrule height #1pt width 0pt \mbox{#1pt}
  \middle|
  \right)
}

\begin{document}

\[
\test{7}\test{8}\test{9}\test{10}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Restoring the default vertical bar

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{yhmath}

\DeclareMathDelimiter{|}{\mathord}{symbols}{"6A}{largesymbols}{"0C}

\newcommand{\test}[1]{%
  \left(
    \vrule height #1pt width 0pt \mbox{#1pt}
  \middle|
  \right)
}

\begin{document}

\[
\test{7}\test{8}\test{9}\test{10}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just when I was thinking "is egreg still on vacation?" you show up and you even show the source code of the symbol. Superb

Comment: @Symbol1 Also `\Vert` suffers from the same problem; it's `"0D`. I'm *never* on vacation! ;-)